HTTP Error 500.30 - ASP.NET Core app failed to start(abp-commercial)
I have a newly created ABP Commercial tiered application. I am deploying the project to Azure using a CI/CD pipeline, and the pipeline works perfectly. However, when I run the app, I encounter the following error: "HTTP Error 500.30 - ASP.NET Core app failed to start."

I deployed the same project on IIS, and it is working fine.

To investigate the target framework issue, I created a new .NET 8 project and published it on  Azure using Visual Studio, and it works.

I also tried the following solution, but it did not work for me:

Configuration issue:
i) Changed hostingModel from "inprocess" to "outofprocess" in the web.config file.
InProcess





Out Of Process

ii) Updated the Azure app service configuration: Platform settings -> Platform -> Changed from 32-bit to 64-bit.


Published the same project on Azure using Visual Studio, but I am still encountering the same error ("HTTP      Error 500.30 - ASP.NET Core app failed to start").

Here it's publish profile:


I also checked the error logs in the Application event log on the Azure App Service and the eventlog.xml file in the Kudu console, where I found the following errors.


Application '/LM/W3SVC/924033019/ROOT' with physical root 'C:\home\site\wwwroot\' failed to load coreclr. Exception message:
CLR worker thread exited prematurely
Process Id: 5284.
File Version: 18.0.24201.8. Description: IIS ASP.NET Core Module V2 Request Handler. Commit:

Application '/LM/W3SVC/924033019/ROOT' with physical root 'C:\home\site\wwwroot\' has exited from Program.Main with exit code = '1'. Please check the stderr logs for more information.
Process Id: 5284.
File Version: 18.0.24201.8. Description: IIS ASP.NET Core Module V2 Request Handler. Commit:   


Either set the ASPNETCORE_DETAILEDERRORS environment variable to 1 or use .CreateDefaultBuilder(args) .UseSetting(WebHostDefaults.DetailedErrorsKey, "true") to see detailed errors. It could be something as simple as a missing DLL.

The screenshots you posted show that more details are already stored in the .\Logs\stdout folder. The files there contain whatever is sent to the console when running your application

How about using Portable?

And the next action is using Self-contained deployment mode.

I resolved the issue by configuring Redis on the Azure App Service and updating the connection string in the "appsettings.json" file. In a tiered application, Redis is essential. For more information, please refer to this link:Redis is essentials for tiered application
